# Ideal bitrates for different video resolutions

Tags: php, laravel, video, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I am building a Video-on-demand service for a closed community. I using FFMPEG for video processing and dash.js for adaptive bitrate player with custom resolution selector. Can somebody please suggest what ideal bitrates should I use while video/audio transcoding?

I am talking about `-b:v` and `-ab` option

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -keyint_min 150 \
-g 150 -tile-columns 4 -frame-parallel 1  -f webm -dash 1 \
-an -vf scale=144:-1 -b:v 120k -dash 1 video_1.webm \
-an -vf scale=240:-1 -b:v 250k -dash 1 video_2.webm \
-an -vf scale=360:-1 -b:v 500k -dash 1 video_3.webm \
-an -vf scale=480:-1 -b:v 750k -dash 1 video_4.webm \
-an -vf scale=720:-1 -b:v 1500k -dash 1 video_5.webm
```

And

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -vn -acodec libvorbis -ab 96k -dash 1 audio_96k.webm
```

Any suggestions/hacks or examples to tackle real-world network situations are appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem and would suit better on an AV site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ideal. Every video is different, and every viewer is different. What is ideal for one viewer is not ideal for another.   Read the Netflix blog on pert title encoding and vmaf. Also look at Akamai state of the internet reports to determine what average global internet connection speeds are.

Comment: Ya, I think running real-world tests and adjusting bitrates to get most of the available average connection speeds only looks better solution now.